# Click event on dynamic element WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like add an event such as onclick or mouseover to a dynamically created element (similar to the .live function in jQuery)...how do I do this using pure javascript without a framework such as jQuery?

```js
document.getElementById('create').onclick = function(){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.addClass('new');
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
};

document.getElementsByClassName('newdiv').onclick = function(){
    alert('Success');
};
```

```css
#create {
     width:150px;
     height:25px;
     margin-bottom:5px;
     background:#ccc;
     border:1px solid #222;   
}

.new {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ffccff;
    border:1px solid #333;   
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="create">
            Click to create div
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to do this from the newly created divs class instead of an id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 26):

Create one handler on the document object. Check the target element's class and node name (tag). If they match, proceed with whatever needs to be done, otherwise ignore the click.

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    if (el.className == "new" && el.nodeName == "DIV") {
        alert("div.new clicked");
    }
};
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/amedr/).

Comment: jQuery's `live` method of even listening works in this fashion, upvote!

Comment: Very nice, this is exactly what I'm looking for...not sure why I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in this particular case when you work with HTMLAnchorElement (A tag), in order to prevent the default execution (when you click on link) with `return false` you will have to call the `event.preventDefault()` first.

Comment: Optimization hint: I would suggest to flip these two conditions, just because of short evaluation. Probably second condition will filter out elements more often :)

if (el.nodeName == "DIV" && el.className == "magic") { ... }

Comment: @lukyer - I would measure this piece of code to see if this is really a bottleneck. Regarding the short-circuiting, are you suggesting there would be fewer `div`elements compared to elements having class `new`? This is purely data-dependent but I would expect to find more divs generally speaking.

Answer (score 3):

[@Anurag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372490/click-event-on-dynamic-element-without-jquery#answer-5372551) is correct but not complete and in most cases will result a lot of integration bugs.

Here is the correct version:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
    // retrieve an event if it was called manually
    event = event || window.event;

    // retrieve the related element
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;

    // for all A tags do the following
    if (el instanceof HTMLAnchorElement )
    {
        //required to make the "return false" to affect
        event.preventDefault();

        window.location.href = "/click.php?href="+encodeURIComponent(el.href);

        //prevent user's click action
        return false;
    }
}, true);
```

This is a basic click-trace functionality affects all links on page to trace/record all link clicks.

Comment: The `return false` here doesn't actually do anything -- that's a jQuery invention that calls event.preventDefault for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/589391.