# One single page of several pages using hash #

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I do singlepage from some pages.

I use `<script type="text/template" id="id_****">content...</script>`
 to store this pages in index file. Here you have an example:

[Simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/r14NzlaqZauzRMPFpE0m?p=preview)

When I clicked hyperlink Browser need use # (hash) in URL. I need navigation with #.

I use `window.location` but I really don't know where to begin. Here you have the way I have tried to do:

[My attempt](http://plnkr.co/edit/2WurmRSM14bBMrXW2FYG?p=preview)

I added *div id="putIn"* to put this page in.

Should work just with JavaScript!

Comment: This is where I started from http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/, And I ended up using the durandaljs framework in the end for SPA development, not sure if that's feasible for you.

Comment: Why use javascript? `name="foo"` would be scrolled to when accessing `url.php#foo`.

Comment: @h Or `id="foo"`. Get with HTML5. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fork of your Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xyPqyl20C4sVL11KqNCS?p=preview

What was changed:

The navigation buttons (forward and back) were given an unique class `navigate`

```
<a href="#" class="navigate" id="back">back</a>
<a href="#" class="navigate" id="forw">forward</a>
```

The `href` attributes were changed to represent the next and previous pages (`id_1`, `id_2`, `id_X`, ...)

Because the navigation links change with the page, an `onclick` listener was added to the `document`.

```
//Listen to all clicks
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    //If we clicked a navigation link
    if (el.className == "navigate" && el.nodeName == "A") {
        //Change the page
        move(el);
    }
};
```

(Source: [Click event on dynamic element WITHOUT jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372490/click-event-on-dynamic-element-without-jquery) )

Created function `move()` to change between pages.

```
  function move(el)
  {
    if (el.getAttribute("href"))
    {
      //Get hash without #
      var hash = el.getAttribute("href").split("#")[1];
      //Change content based on hash
      document.getElementById("putIn").innerHTML = document.getElementById(hash).innerHTML;

    }
  }
```

A better solution would be to move the navigation links outside the `#putIn` div and just keep track of what "page" is currently displayed. This would enable you to add / remove pages without the need to update the code.

Comment: Thanks. Just in my case I have different count of buttons with different function.